# Create desired flux density at a desired distance from an electromagnet of simple shape?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

total layman here!
I was reading about an experiment on the effects of low-amplitude ELF AC magnetic fields on an ionic solution. The required field amplitude of 0.04 microteslas was generated by running a current between two electrodes 10mm apart inside a chamber of test liquid.

Thinking about this lead me to what might be an obvious (or stupid)question: how does one create the same conditions (or, at least, same flux density) in the chamber, but with an *externally applied* ELF AC field?  The experiment requires a magnetic flux density of 0.04 microteslas in the chamber (assuming AC magnetic field amplitude is equivalent to flux density?).
If you have a simple solenoid of known dimensions, turns, core, etc., with its dipole directed at the chamber, and you know the distance from the chamber (say, 100mm), can you calculate the required amperage for the solenoid to produce a 0.04 microtesla field density at 100mm out?

So I guess I am really asking: can you figure out how to create a desired flux density at a desired distance from an electromagnet of simple shape?